# Why doesn't WPF Animation respecting height or width values?

Tags: wpf, animation

Why does this animation result in the window moving across left to right in the original position first then jumping to the other position even though I set the width and height properties before the animation started.  It seems to reset the height value when it starts to show the width and then changes it back when doing the second animation.

```
  Sub ShowTitle(ByVal Text As String)
        tb_text.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
        tb_text.Height = 5
        tb_text.Width = 0
        tb_text.Text = Text
        tb_text.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible


        Dim SB As New Animation.Storyboard

        Dim FIW = New Animation.DoubleAnimation(0, 400, New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
        SB.Children.Add(FIW)
        Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetName(FIW, tb_text.Name)
        Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(FIW, New PropertyPath(WidthProperty))

        Dim FIH = New Animation.DoubleAnimation(5.0, 50.0, New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
        FIH.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        SB.Children.Add(FIH)
        Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetName(FIH, tb_text.Name)
        Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(FIH, New PropertyPath(HeightProperty))

        SB.Begin(Me)
    End Sub
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? The code is performing "exactly" what you have told it to do. Each time ShowTitle() is called, it will make the height 5 and width 0 and then animate as per the precedence i.e. width animation from 0 to 400 and followed by height animation from 5 to 50.

Comment: that's not what happens though.  it fails to reset the height value to 5 and only changes the width.  Then when this is done the next animation effect does it's job but it wasn't supposed to start with a width of 50 it was supposed to have a width of 5.  Re result is it appears that it's resetting itself instead of a smooth transition.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this relates to your scenario, but I just spent 4 hours tracking down an animation of Width/Height (in my case of main window) bug.  In all my desperate attempts at grasping for anything, I ended up stumbling over this post. In the end, for me "the fix" turned out to be switching the project back to use .NET Framework 3.5.  If you have that luxury, try that and see if the behavior changes.

While both you and me have issues with animations and width/height, I found another person on [MS connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=window%2bwidth%2banimation) who reported width/height not working property with triggers either (.NET framework 4.0 only).  I built a very small test project that illustrates the issue and submitted my own bug report, but I'm not really holding my breath since the other guy posted his issue 20 months ago and his issue was "in triage and resolution" ever since.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Non-simultaneous width and height animation which then works fine when I set back to Framework 3.5. How is this not a bigger deal?